# How to insert .doc file content into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, doc

I need to insert a doc file into mysql table using php.

I have the file format like :

[image: demo.doc].

I want all the titles (e.g. `Resume`) be inserted into to `Type` column, and subtitles (e.g.`Jobtitle`) be inserted into `title` field in mysql table.

I have a form

```
<FORM ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" ACTION="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}" METHOD=POST>
Upload this file: <INPUT NAME="userfile" TYPE="file">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="submit" name=submit></FORM>
```

So, how could I make it happen?

Comment: just upload the file and store a path to it

Comment: Nice! I haven't seen all-caps HTML since the late 90s. :)

Comment: @Álvaro: I _was_ lucky. Not so now...

Answer (score 2):

YOu have to save it as a binary.

Here a good tutorial:

http://mirificampress.com/permalink/saving_a_file_into_mysql

Answer (score 0):

You have the following choices:

- Store the file in the database using the BLOB column type. The file then physically resides in the database. For performance reasons, this is probably not the best idea if you are storing lots of files.
- Store the file in a directory, then store the path to the file in your database. That means, everytime you do a retrival, you look up the path in the database first, then using that path you should be able to fetch the file using PHP.

The second method would probably offer better performance in most cases.

Comment: i need file content should be stored in different fields.. like job title in job title field. description in description field

Comment: @fatal: here's a blog post about performance of blobs in applications that need to scale: http://mysqldatabaseadministration.blogspot.com/2008/01/i-will-not-blob.html

Comment: @Ravin, is there any reason why you can't store the data in the database by parsing the docx document? This way you can index the data and perform searches on it etc. If you want to then generate the docx document, you can retrive the data and generate the file on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the question you want to read the content of the .doc files into a MySQL table using PHP.

.doc is a proprietary format which means reading in PHP is going to be exceptionally difficult. You'll probably want to look at the COM functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php

However, these are only available on the Windows version of PHP (for obvious reasons).

If you can save the Word files as RTF or TXT you may have a better chance. Newer versions of word also use the .docx format which is the document saved in an open XML format, which again will be easier to parse with PHP.